# non-HTML5 browsers send raw file content with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, flash, filereader, fileapi, arraybuffer

Is there a way to read the raw file content of the file and send the binary data to the server with an XMLHttpRequest ajax request?
In HTML5 browsers I can do this:

```
reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
reader.onload = function(e) {
   xhr.send(e.target.result);
}
```

There are some libraries like [FileAPI](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI) or [FileReader polyfill](https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader) but none of them support `readAsArrayBuffer()` and if I use `readAsBinaryString()` the binary data will be screwed up while converting to String, and extra characters will be added to the content.

Any suggestions?